# LEAFLET - How to make a vibration or motion effect to a map marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet

How can we make a leaflet marker moving o vibrate effect?
Thanks

```
<script>

let map = L.map('map').setView([43.310789, -1.970963],13.5)
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager_labels_under/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
    subdomains: 'abcd',
    maxZoom: 19
}).addTo(map);

//MARKER TO VIBRATE:
 var marker = L.marker([40.417517, -3.703791],{icon: redIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup("City").openPopup();

</script>
```

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#overlay-animations

Comment: I'm looking for an effect to stand out, like a vibration or a little repetitive displacement, etc. Can i find it? Thanks.